# Javascript and sqlite request

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, request

I have a little Problem. I got the following simple SQL request:

```
async userexists(pUsername) {
    await this._sequilze.query("SELECT username, userpw, grade FROM users WHERE username = pUser",
    {replacements: {pUser: pUsername}})
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
}
```

But I don't know why I get this Errormessage:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: pUser`

I mean, I replace the pUser with my parameter pUsername. It works when inserted into the database.
A request with hardcoded Data is still working too like `WHERE grade = 1`

I hope you can help me

Thanks in advance,

JN

Answer (score 1):

According to this reference for Sequelize (which it seems you are using):
[Sequelize replacements doc](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements)

You should use ":key" in your SQL query, in your case replace "pUser" with ":pUser" to have it replaced

```
async userexists(pUsername) {
    await this._sequilze.query("SELECT username, userpw, grade FROM users WHERE username = :pUser",
    {replacements: {pUser: pUsername}})
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
```

}